# SQLAlchemy: How do I avoid this inconsistency between ORM cache and DB

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Here's a simplified version of my problem. I have a program `query.py`:

```py
import time
from models import Ball, session

time.sleep(1)
r = session.query(Ball).filter(Ball.color=='red').first()
print(f'Red ball color is {r.color}')
time.sleep(2)
b = session.query(Ball).filter(Ball.color=='blue').first()
print(f'Blue ball color is {b.color}')
print(f'Red ball id is {r.id}, blue ball id is {b.id}')
```

When I run `query.py` at the same time as `modify.py` (included below), I get the following output:

```
$ python modify.py &! python query.py
Red ball color is red                                                                                                                                                   
Blue ball color is red                                                                                                                                                  
Red ball id is 1, blue ball id is 1
```

The problem is that the blue ball is red!

Here is the content of `models.py`:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as sao
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative as saed

Base = saed.declarative_base()

class Ball(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ball'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    color = sa.Column(sa.String)

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sao.Session(engine)
```

And here is `modify.py`:

```py
import time
from models import Ball, session

session.query(Ball).delete()
b = Ball(color='red')
session.add(b)
session.commit()
time.sleep(2)
b.color = 'blue'
session.add(b)
session.commit()
```

I find it very strange that I get an inconsistency here between my DB query (that sees the latest DB state) and the object returned via the SQLAlchemy identiy map for my DB query (which is stale, reflecting the DB state the first time the row in question was read). I know that restarting my transaction in the `query.py` process before each query will invalidate the cached objects in the identity map and result in the blue ball being blue here, but that's a non-starter.

I'd be happy if the blue ball were blue -- i.e. if the DB query and object it returned agreed -- or if the blue ball query returned `None` -- i.e. if the concurrent DB modification was not visible in the query transaction. But I seem to be stuck in the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It seems the underlying issue is that SQLite support is buggy by default in Python, and SQLAlchemy knowingly inherits this buggy behavior.** I eventually figured out how to get both possible correct behaviors, i.e. either make the blue ball blue, by invalidating the identity map/cache without cancelling the current transaction, or make the query for blue balls return `None`, by running the `query.py` in a properly isolated transaction.

### Achieving isolation / making the blue ball query return `None`

I found that setting the isolation level, by passing `isolation_level=<level>` to `create_engine` had no effect, i.e. this didn't provide a way to make the `query.py` run in a transaction that is isolated from the writes by `modify.py`, where the query for blue balls would return `None`. After reading about [isolation levels in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/isolation.html) it seems that setting the isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` should accomplish this, but it does not. However, [the SQLAlchemy documentation warns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html?highlight=sqlite#pysqlite-serializable) that by default SQLite transactions are broken:

> In the section *Database Locking Behavior / Concurrency*, we refer to the `pysqlite` driver’s assortment of issues that prevent several features of SQLite from working correctly. The `pysqlite` DBAPI driver has several long-standing bugs which impact the correctness of its transactional behavior. In its default mode of operation, SQLite features such as SERIALIZABLE isolation, transactional DDL, and SAVEPOINT support are non-functional, and in order to use these features, workarounds must be taken.

That page goes on to suggest workarounds to get functioning transactions, and those workarounds work for me. Namely, adding the following to the bottom of `models.py` achieves the isolation behavior where the blue balls query returns `None`:

```py
@sa.event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def do_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    # disable pysqlite's emitting of the BEGIN statement entirely.
    # also stops it from emitting COMMIT before any DDL.
    dbapi_connection.isolation_level = None

@sa.event.listens_for(engine, "begin")
def do_begin(conn):
    # emit our own BEGIN
    conn.exec_driver_sql("BEGIN")
```

With this change, the output becomes

```
$ python modify.py &! python query.py
Red ball color is red                                                                                                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                      
  File "query.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(f'Blue ball color is {b.color}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'color'
```

I.e. the DB write in `modify.py` that makes the ball blue is not visible in the (implicit) transaction in `query.py`.

### Making the query and returned object agree / making the blue ball blue

On the other hand, to get the behavior where the the blue ball is blue, it's enough to invalidate the cache/identity map before each query, using `session.expire_all()`. I.e., changing `query.py` to the following works:

```
import time
from models import Ball, session

time.sleep(1)
r = session.query(Ball).filter(Ball.color=='red').first()
print(f'Red ball color is {r.color}')
time.sleep(2)
# Added this line:
session.expire_all()
b = session.query(Ball).filter(Ball.color=='blue').first()
print(f'Blue ball color is {b.color}')
print(f'Red ball id is {r.id}, blue ball id is {b.id}')
```

With this change, the output becomes

```
$ python modify.py &! python query.py                                                                                                                                
Red ball color is red                                                                                                                                                   
Blue ball color is blue                                                                                                                                                 
Red ball id is 1, blue ball id is 1
```